# How do I check truthy when using Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements, ternary, truthy

I am having issues with using the ternary operator and checking if a value is truthy or not. I have a feeling that my syntax is incorrect. Below is the instructions on what I need to do to pass this step, and the two lines of code with the comments "here" is what I wrote for the solution. Please help me.

"Use a ternary operator to check if currentTitle evaluates to a truthy value. If it does, set playingSong.textContent to currentTitle. Otherwise, set it to an empty string.
Then below that, use a ternary operator to check if currentArtist is truthy. If so, set songArtist.textContent to currentArtist. Otherwise, set it to empty string."

```
const setPlayerDisplay = () => {
  const playingSong = document.getElementById("player-song-title");
  const songArtist = document.getElementById("player-song-artist");
  const currentTitle = userData?.currentSong?.title;
  const currentArtist = userData?.currentSong?.artist;
  currentTitle ? playingSong.textContent = currentTitle : playingSong.textContent = ""; //here
  currentArtist ? songArtist.textContent = currentArtist : songArtist.textContent = ""; //here
};
```

I tried writing it differently, but I still am getting an error. Here is my other attempt.

```
currentTitle = currentTitle ?  playingSong.textContent = currentTitle : playingSong.textContent = "";
currentArtist = currentArtist ? songArtist.textContent = currentArtist : songArtist.textContent = "";
```

Comment: "I still am getting an error." What is the error?

Comment: My use of the ternary operator in the code, it doesn't pass the test. It's suppose to change the value of the playingSong to the value of the currentTitle if it is truthy, if not then it will make the value of playingSong to an empty string. But I believe I am writing the ternary syntax incorrectly.

Comment: Your code is doing fine, it works as intended. I can (should) be rewritten/simplified to `if (currentTitle) { playingSong.textContent = currentTitle } else { playingSong.textContent = "" }`, `playingSong.textContent = currentTitle ? currentTitle : "";` or `playingSong.textContent = currentTitle || "";` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting 2 separate assignments **inside** the ternary operator, like this:

```js
condition ? a = x : a = y;
```

You should instead write a single assignment that uses a ternary expression, and let the ternary operator decide on what value to use, like this:

```js
a = condition ? x : y;
```

For the above it doesn't matter if `condition` is boolean (true/false) or if it is truthy/falsy.

Applied to your code, this is what you should use:

```js
playingSong.textContent = currentTitle ? currentTitle : "";
songArtist.textContent = currentArtist ? currentArtist : "";
```

Finally if using the ternary operator is not an actual requirement, then this can be shortened even further:

```js
playingSong.textContent = currentTitle || "";
songArtist.textContent = currentArtist || "";
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that instead of `currentTitle || ""` you could also use the [nullish coalescent operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing): `currentTitle ?? ""`. The `??` operator will always return the first operand, unless its value is "nullish", i. e. `null` or `undefined`. This would allow for the assignment of the first operand having values like `0` or `false`.